# Force activity to call onCreate() using startActivity when the launchMode is singleTask

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My activity launch mode is set to be `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

When I call `startActivity()` to launch it from another activity it brings it on top from the last state it was.

Scenario:

Activity A launches Activity B

Activity B launches Activity A

Activity A is brought with old data

What flags do I use to force it start clean and calls `onCreate()`?

Knowing that I have to use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to maintain 
regular application flow and cannot swap to `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Thanks

**Edit (1):**

```
launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

along with `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

It solved the problem I'm asking about, but it created a worst problem

Now when I finish activity A (The launched by Activity B that was launched by Activity A) I find myself ending up to last application I was using, where it should be landing to activity B.

Comment: why don't you try and use `startActivityForResult` and use the details from B on A on the `onActivityResult()`

Comment: @IsaiahJ I clearly mentioned that I must stick to singleTask and can't switch to SingleTop as it breaks the intended flow.

Comment: @aminography I thought about that, but there is a scenario where activity B relaunch activity A which keeps and requires to keep its old state, that's why I'm using singleTask, I need to maintain this scenario and find solution for the mentioned scenario in the question.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, but it wasn't really clear imo. I suggested some edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `onNewIntent` to know `Activity` A is relaunched. So you should do initialization in both `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` when the launch mode is `singleTask`.

**Activity A:**

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        // do initialization
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but there is a scenario where activity B relaunch activity A which keeps and requires to keep its old state, that's why I'm using singleTask, I need to maintain this scenario and find solution for the mentioned scenario in the question.

Comment: I made some changes. I hope it helps.